# Authorizing Sections of component with Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle this. I have a list of roles that are allowed to view a component, however, I don't quite know the best way to handle it in the component if different roles are allowed to view certain parts of the component.

```
<component editable="{{ Entrust::hasRole(['admin', 'role2', 'role3']) }}" id="{{ $project->id }}"></paymentinfo>
```

Comment: Best is too subjective for this Q&A format. If you need code optimization, check out [https://codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: show/hide the component if the role allows it. pass a boolean from laravel to determine if the component should be displayed for that specific user.any other security would be done on the backend since anyone could easily view the component even though it's "hidden"